# Why is my GeoJSON polygon only displayed as a line?

Tags: geojson

I'm trying to convert a simple shapefile drawn in GIS to GeoJSON. However, it's not working and I don't know why.

[image]

The file converts with QGIS (Save As), but the http://geojsonlint.com/ doesn't plot the shape, nor does my Mapbox application - it plots it as a line.

I've set the CRS to EPSG 3857.

Here's the GeoJSON, http://pastebin.com/93e0wWzA

Do you need the Shapefile to figure this out?

Comment: Perhaps it is because of EPSG:3857. Geojson is going to drop out CRS and use only CRS84 coordinates https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-butler-geojson-04

Comment: I changed the Shapefile to CRS84 and converted and still have the same issue

Comment: could you also past the new `GeoJSON`?

Answer (score 1):

Geojsonlint seems to suppose that GeoJSON is in WGS84 coordinate system which is also the only officially supported CRS in the newest GeoJSON specification (draft) https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-butler-geojson-04

I converted your GeoJSON into epsg:4326 with ogr2ogr by using command

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson -s_srs epsg:3857 -t_srs epsg:4326 geojsontest2.json geojsontest.json
```

The new GeoJSON file does show in geojsonlint.

[image]

Comment: Hello - Can you share your ogr2ogr process? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Could there be a possibility that the coordinates would be represented in a different location - the Polygon isn't supposed to be there. Is that related to changing the CRS?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that something has gone wrong with the first step when you converted your "simple shapefile drawn in GIS" into geojson? Nobody can say anything about that without making a test with the original shapefile.

Comment: Would it be helpful to see the original Shapefile?

Comment: Naturally, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17924/discussion-between-smacfadyen-and-user30184).

Comment: Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ti74dy1wrc2uwy/Atlantic%20Margin.zip?dl=0

Comment: The polygon sits exactly at the same place when I convert your shapefile into geojson and tell that source is using epsg:3857. Show next a screen capture about where it should be. Think also carefully to which coordinate system you have digitized and saved it and if it really was epsg:3857. Your shapefile does not contain .prj file to tell it. Guessing the coordinate system is not my favorite play.